# Responsive Web Design.. Unwanted Right Padding/Margin on Ipad

Tags: css, wordpress, ipad, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Hi guys as the title says.. i keep getting this horriable right margin when i go down to ipad viewport size and when i view it on the ipad hence you get horizontal scroll bars.. major issue and quite annoying... But when i get down to the view of iPhone it goes away.. really strange.. can any one please help..... you can check it out here

I've deleted all elements from the page and i still get the problem.. so annoying

[Click Here to View Problem](http://www.fuss-beauty.co.uk/home/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your css, your section and footer style rules have a negative margin left and right. I took them out and it seemed to fix it for me. Perhaps look to see if you have some in your header as well?

I'm not sure why you have a negative margin here, but if you absolutely need this margin at higher window sizes, look into adding these rules into your ipad breakpoints.

Comment: that seem to do the trick for the iPad, but now when i view it on my phone.. the background colors dont reach the edge of the window!!..weird